# Sending array of pointers to function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, opengl-es

I have an array of pointers declared at the top of my file like this.

```
GLuint *buffers[2];
```

And I wish to pass the actual values of the array to a gl function to generate the buffers:

```
GL_API void GL_APIENTRY glGenBuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint *buffers);
```

This is the API entry. I can't change the function, Khronos/Apple (by extension) can.

I tried:

```
glGenBuffers(2, *buffers);
```

With no luck.
I don't know wether this is possible and I'm assuming it's not but if there is a chance it is it would make my program a whole lot easier to write.

This example isn't how I'll actually be using it, I'm planning to write a request based Geometry loader that will generate all the buffers and split the mallocs into larger ones, so as to decrease calls and speed up performance.

EDIT: I can't change the glGenBuffers function, if this is what people are suggesting.

EDIT: I'm realising now how ridiculous my request seems to be, I was just hoping that maybe c had a feature that said these are pointers so edit their values, upon thinking about this in detail it seems ludicrous. I'll probably just allocate an array of buffers, than make my original pointers (In the separate class file), equal this value by going: *originalBuffer[i] = generatedBuffer[i]; In a loop.

Comment: Did you try calling `glGenBuffers(2, buffers)` and declaring `void glGenBuffers(int, GLuint**)` ? Did you enable all warnings and debugging info in your compiler? Did you use the debugger?

Comment: Yes to the former, how would overwriting the actual function declaration change anything? Yes to the debugging, I'm using LLDB.

Comment: But the function's prototype is unknown... According to the given code I suppose that it is `void`/`int` glGenBuffers(int, GLuint *). Does it so?

Answer (score 0):

Given the API entry (copied from your comments into the question), and your variable declaration, you can't pass an array of pointers to the function.

You could write:

```
GLuint buffer[2];

glGenBuffers(2, buffer);
```

You could write:

```
GLuint *buffers[2];
buffers[0] = malloc(number * sizeof(GLuint));
buffers[1] = malloc(number * sizeof(GLuint));
glGenBuffers(number, buffers[0]);
glGenBuffers(number, buffers[1]);
```

Either of these respects the API.

Comment: The latter defeats the purpose of my code entirely, I want a single call to the function and to reduce the amount of mallocs, I realise now that I  can just use a temporary buffer array and then edit the original buffers afterwards. And the former wouldn't maintain the functionality. I apologise for being brash, the only fix to this problem appears to be a design change.

Comment: I agree that you'll need to change the design of your code so that conforms to the API you want to use. Since I don't know how you're planning to use the buffers, or how your code is designed (and neither does anyone else on SO, at least based on the information in your question), it is not possible to help you much more.  What you can't sensibly do is abuse the API function; that won't help you at all. You'd have to demonstrate with conclusive timing evidence that the number of `malloc()` calls is a material factor in the performance of your code — frankly, it is extremely unlikely to be one.

Comment: When I'm loading huge geometry files it helps to reduce malloc calls as any speed up greatly improves my application loading speed and loading new content etc.

Comment: No; if you're reading huge geometry files, I/O time dominates anything you're doing with memory allocation.  On modern machines, it is pretty much always the case that if you're doing I/O, I/O dominates.  The exceptions tend to be when the I/O is already cached by the O/S.

Comment: It is flash based hardware, my point being any overhead reduction is good. Also 1000 mallocs of small geometry (boxes and such), would be better suited to one malloc call. Furthermore I'm considering creating a mechanism to group geometry into single files to reduce the amount of freads and whatnot.